# How does user log into Facebook app after authorizing it

Tags: php

I appreciate all those who help by giving usable answers, so the question is quite simple, but I just can't figure it out, I have understood the part that talks about getting user authorization via the Oauth dialog when creating an app that's going to be in the Facebook chrome within a canvas. Basically you just access the signed request parameter and prompt the user to authorize the app with whatever requirements it may need, you know, like user info involving friends list, user id, name, ability to post photos on wall etc. it's like this:

```
<?php 

 $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";

 $canvas_page = "YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE_URL";

 $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

 $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

 list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

 $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

 if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
 } else {
        echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
 } 
 ?>
```

if i'd need anymore data, i'd specify it using the scope parameter at the end of my canvas page url, you know, access to friends list, ability to post and so on. so i think this part would go into my index.php file, and when i do get the user info, i'd store it in respective tables inside a database. i'd then start a session using all the data and need for the app to work, and when the user logs out, i'd destroy the session. one thing i don't get is, what happens when the user logs in to Facebook again? he/she would have already authorized my app and i guess it would be in their app list, i don't get how, when they click on the url in the list, i'd again get their data and log them into my up. the authorization is like signing up, what about the logging in? i'd need this to start a session, load their saved data from my database etc. i know it's a very rudimentary question, but i'm new to this Facebook app thing, and not a pro programmer. i have read the documentation, but still don't get the logging in after the user authorizes the app, how would that work? thanks in advance for the help, an example would be nice.

Comment: You need to get an app id for your app first, here:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps
Also you need the Facebook SDK for PHP alongside:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook login is really both in one. It checks to see if the app is authorized, if it is it logs the user in and returns their FB user information rather than having them reauthorize the application. It's up to you to save the relevant data and then check your database against what the FB API is returning as a user to actually log them into your site.

When I use this I save their FB user ID to my database, then when the login process returns a Facebook user I compare that user ID to my database and load the associated user.

Comment: thanks for the answer, really clears up things for me, so the code that is used using the facebook php sdk to get authorization also works to send the app the user ID, every time they click on it?so in my index file, the code i'd use to first prompt the user for authorization would double up as login code? when they authorize it, facebook would give me their id, i'd see if it exists in my DB, if not, add it and start a session for them(logging them in) if they are, log them in as well? thanks a lot!